# Polynomial approximation does not represent accurate approximation of line passing through data points in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, approximation, polynomial-approximations

I am working on the task where I have to Augment the data. For data augmentation, I have to do polynomial approximation of the data (Non linear data). But if I do the polynomial approximation, I am not getting an accurate approximation of the data.

Below are 35 points which I used as an original data.

```
x = [0.7375, 0.7405, 0.7445, 0.7488, 0.7515, 0.7545, 0.7593, 0.7625, 0.7657, 0.7687, 0.7715, 0.776, 0.7794, 0.7826, 0.7889, 0.7916, 0.7945, 0.8011, 0.8038, 0.8079, 0.8125, 0.8168, 0.8233, 0.826, 0.8287, 0.8318, 0.8361, 0.8391, 0.845, 0.8506, 0.8534, 0.8563, 0.8595, 0.8625, 0.8734]

y = [7797.61, 7829.59, 7833.6, 7837.02, 7854.76, 7862.18, 7893.06, 7927.04, 7946.49, 7975.83, 8038.12, 8110.94, 8115.37, 8125.11, 8172.58, 8182.54, 8215.06, 8232.01, 8274.98, 8272.71, 8243.45, 8242.93, 8225.08, 8199.25, 8180.92, 8143.29, 8152.09, 8136.59, 8164.3, 8202.04, 8203.57, 8174.67, 8192.0, 8201.25, 8131.32]
```

Below picture describes you more.
[image]

I have used `from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures`.

```
x_plot = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)

model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(42), Ridge(alpha=1e-3))
model.fit(x, y)
y_plot = model.predict(x_plot)
r2 = model.score(x,y)
```

Where `x` and `y` is my original data, 35 points.

I want to get closest to perfect (more accurate) approximation as obtained curve does not represent the accurate enough.

Comment: What polynomial degree have you selected? Does increasing polynomial degree give you an improved fit? Can you share your raw 35 points to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have edited my post and mentioned the X and Y points. I also tried with the  number of degree ranging from 10 to 20 but it still did not show the better fitted line

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something risky and I'm not sure you realize it. For N data points, an N degree polynomial can always fit the data exactly. Your plot is a degree 42 polynomial for 35 data points. You are certainly overfitting.

Perfect performance should never be the goal for fitting a model - the ability to generalize to unseen data should be the ultimate goal. Consider reading about overfitting online to better understand the problem here

Comment: True, but I wonder why the plot doesn't show an overfitted polynomial.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. I suspect there's a bug in the code or maybe some effects of Ridge's regularization, but the idea still holds

Comment: I tried to check some articles in internet but could not find one which gives better result. It would be nice if you help me to find a bug in code and send a corrected code

Comment: Where do `deg` and `i` come from?

Comment: deg=[42] so deg[i] = 42

Answer (score 0):

Your method is sensitive to the value of `alpha` in `Ridge`. The docs for scikit-learn say that you can use `RidgeCV` instead of `Ridge` to choose `alpha` based on leave-one-out cross validation, for example:

```
model = make_pipeline(
    PolynomialFeatures(...),
    RidgeCV(alphas=np.logspace(-10, 10)))
```

If you're just trying to approximate a curve passing through all those points, you could get a close curve with a `SplineTransformer`, without needing to use a high polynomial degree. For example:

```
model = make_pipeline(
    SplineTransformer(n_knots=5, degree=3),
    RidgeCV(alphas=np.logspace(-10, 10)))
```

---

The last two points on your graph concern me: you can find a polynomial or spline curve that comes close to both of them, but now you're assuming the shape of data between them, based on a very small amount of information. Overfitting, like @MikeL said. Any error in measurement of the last point would change your model much more than error in, say, the 5th point.